# Search and Bubble Sort Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

Alright, so I'm really having trouble with this lab for my class.
Here's the problem:

Initialization: Randomly initialize a list of size 200 with integer values between 0 and 100.
Part 1: Search
You are to implement a function which searches a list for an occurence of a value. It should not depend on the list being pre-sorted.

Search
Section     Specification   Comments
INPUT:  list, value     An initialized list
COMPUTATION:

```
Loop over all elements in list.
    If current element equals value, store as index.
If value not found, ensure index is -1.
```

RETURN:     index   -1 if value not found

```
Prompt the user once for an element (an integer from 0 to 100) to search for.
Call your search function with the number to search for and the list.
Display whether the number was found, and if found, a location where it can be found within the list.
```

Part 2: Sort
You are to implement a function which sorts a list in ascending (0, 1, ...) order. You are not permitted to use JavaScript's sort() method.
There are many ways to sort a list of which you may implement any method you see fit, provided it sorts a list in ascending order. Below describes Bubble Sort, one of the most straight-forward approaches to sorting.

Sort
Section     Specification   Comments
INPUT:  list    An initialized list
OTHER VARIABLES:    swap
n   Indicates if swap occurred.
How far to search in the list.
COMPUTATION:

```
Set n to size of list - 1.
Set swap to FALSE.
Loop over element 0 through element n in the list.
    If current element > next element
        Swap current element and next element.
        Set swap to TRUE.
If swap is TRUE, repeat from step 2. n -= 1.
If swap is FALSE, return the now sorted list.

Gradually sorts a list.
```

nth item is correctly placed.
RETURN:     list

```
Call your sort function for your list. You are not permitted to call Javascript's sort() method.
Display the (sorted) list.
```

I'm not asking you to do my homework but can you please just point me in the right direction? I figured out how to do the bubble sort but the search part is what I'm mostly having problems with.

Comment: Hi Hannah, welcome to SO. Can you post the JavaScript code which you have written so far- or at least the pertinent parts of it...

Comment: At what step are you facing problem ?

Answer (score 2):

```
function search(array, value)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        if (array[i] === value)
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

For Bubble Sort implementation please read [this](http://www.metalshell.com/source_code/112/Javascript_Bubble_Sort.html).

Also, you can use this solution:

```
function search(array, value)
{
    return array.indexOf(value);
}
```

Comment: With pleasure. Did you try this out?